# How to compare huge files with progress information

Tags: command-line, file-comparison, large-files

In a Unix command line context I would like to compare two truly huge files (around 1TB each), preferable with a progress indicator.

I have tried `diff` and `cmp`, and they both crashed the system (macOS Mojave), let alone giving me a progress bar.

What's the best way to compare these very large files?

#### Additional Details:

1. I just want to check that they are identical.
2. `cmp` crashed the system in a way that the system did restart by itself. :-( Maybe the system ran out of memory?

Comment: Can you be more specific than "crashed the system"?  Did you get an error message?  Did your system spontaneously reboot?  Did the shell seem to just hang uninterruptibly?  Also, what exactly are you looking for?  Is `cmp` enough for your use case -- i.e. do you just want to figure out if the files are identical or not?  Or do you want to know every difference?

Comment: How exactly did you use these commands? Did you, for example, also try to read a very large file with a command substitution?

Comment: @Kusalananda I just issued `cmp /Volumes/TmpDisk/LargeImage.dmg /Volumes/BkpDisk/LargeImage.dmg` - and waited. Approx. an hour later the system rebooted. This was reproducible.

Comment: `cmp` is memory efficient, doesn't load files to memory. It seems more like an environment or data/filesystem issue. Can your OS handle these files, in general?

Comment: "Around 1TB": I'm guessing the files are *exactly* the same size, to the exact byte ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pv` as a progress indicator, and pipe that to the `shasum` function to check the hash to see if they are identical.

```
pv file1 | shasum
1.08MiB 0:00:00 [57.5MiB/s] [====================================>] 100%            
303462e848ecbec5f8ab12718fa6239713eda1c6  -

pv file2 | shasum
1.08MiB 0:00:00 [57.5MiB/s] [====================================>] 100%            
303462e848ecbec5f8ab12718fa6239713eda1c6  -
```

Comment: Looks pretty promising! Will try it out.

Comment: Works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get information about the fact they are identical or not one possible way is to use hash. Command like this will give you `sha1` hash of files:

```
shasum file1 file2
```

Expected result is something like:

```
ddfdb3a7fc6fc7ca714c9e2930fa685136e90448 file1
ddfdb3a7fc6fc7ca714c9e2930fa685136e90448 file2
```

Comment: Did you estimate how long it takes to get an shasum of Tbyte files?

Comment: @Philippos, do you think other possible methods will be much faster? And in some cases this is the only possible way (files on two different machines). IMHO the bottleneck will be access to the storage.

Comment: Could be. I don't know, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: Interesting idea. - How likely is it for two large files to be different but to have the same hash?

Comment: Also, `shasum` doesn't output progress information. (And neither `bar` or `progress` seem to hook on it for progress indication.)

Comment: @halloleo , yes, there is no progress indicator. About same hash - this is named collision and probability is 2^61 you can check this Q/A: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867191/probability-of-sha1-collisions

Comment: @RomeoNinov Thanks for the Q/A link. Very interesting!

Answer (score 1):

You could estimate total time by cutting off a few GB from each file, timing that, and scaling up appropriately. A progress bar has to count bytes too -- it might extend the time by 50% all by itself.

In fact, you might use a loop to cut the files into 100 sections (using dd, or head -c + tail -c, with pipes), use your preferred comparison tool, and report each section.

Advantages:

(a) Gives you a progress report at 1% intervals.

(b) If there are differences early on, you get your answer earlier and can exit the loop without checking the rest of the file.

(c) Comparing 10GB files will probably not reboot your system.

(d) You can adapt this to do more detailed analysis on the known regions of the file: divide and conquer.

(e) You can assign sections of the address range to multiple CPUs.